# Calculate distance between two values in a cycle

Tags: geometry, analysis

[image]

This is a circle having numbers from 0 to 10. 0 = 10.
I'm trying to find the minimal distance between 2 numbers on this circle.
Examples:

0 and 1 => 1

0 and 2 => 2

1 and 6 => 5

1 and 9 => 2

2 and 9 => 3

10 and 0 => 0

9 and 9 => 0

(Application: useful to calculate the similarity of two colors hues on the color wheel.)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distance between $a$ and $b$ is just

$$\min(|a-b|, 10-|a-b|)$$

because $|a-b|$ is the distance between $a$ and $b$ in the clockwise direction, and $10-|a-b|$ is the distance between $a$ and $b$ in the counterclockwise/anticlockwise direction. Taking the minimum of the two values yields the distance between the two.